# Stemming problems in Solr

Tags: solr, internationalization, django-haystack

I have a solr schema generated by Django Haystack for searching our database. When using the default text search some results are not found which seems to be due to special characters and/or Swedish letters. The pattern doesn't seem very consistent and I can't figure out what's happening.

I've tried modifying the schema.xml for Swedish but it doesn't seem to work. I also tried to change the KeywordTokenizerFactory but it didn't help. Am I just missing something with regards to how to setup Solr here? I'm not very familiar with it yet.

Examples:

1. If I search for the word *spelmansrörelse*, I get zero result. If I leave out the last letter, *spelmansrörels*, I get the correct results. In other cases the Swedish letters å,ä,ö seem to work fine.
2. If I search for *192b_2* or *367_3*, both of which exist in the database and should be indexed, I get zero results. If I search for other parts of the object I do get the results. A similar search *367_11* does give the correct results despite it also containing an underscore. The difference seems to be that there are two characters after the underscore?

The results are the same if I search directly from Solr, leaving out Django Haystack.

Solr is version 4.1.0.2013.01.16.17.21.36 and we'll move to a newer version soon. Here's my schema.xml if it helps figure this out.

```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" ?>
  <schema name="default" version="1.5">
  <types>
    <fieldtype name="string"  class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldtype name="binary" class="solr.BinaryField"/>

    <!-- Numeric field types that manipulate the value into
         a string value that isn't human-readable in its internal form,
         but with a lexicographic ordering the same as the numeric ordering,
         so that range queries work correctly. -->
    <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" sortMissingLast="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" sortMissingLast="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" sortMissingLast="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" sortMissingLast="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="sint" class="solr.SortableIntField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="slong" class="solr.SortableLongField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="sfloat" class="solr.SortableFloatField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="sdouble" class="solr.SortableDoubleField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>

    <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tfloat" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tlong" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <!-- A Trie based date field for faster date range queries and date faceting. -->
    <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

    <fieldType name="point" class="solr.PointType" dimension="2" subFieldSuffix="_d"/>
    <fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>
    <fieldtype name="geohash" class="solr.GeoHashField"/>

    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_sv.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Swedish"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="text_sv" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_sv.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        {% comment %}<filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>{% endcomment %}
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Swedish"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
          <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
        -->
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_sv.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Swedish"/>
        <!-- <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/> -->
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
          <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
        -->
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="ngram" class="solr.TextField" >
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="edge_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="1">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
  </types>

  <fields>
    <!-- general -->
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true"/>
    <field name="django_ct" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="django_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored ="true"/>

    <dynamicField name="*_i"  type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_s"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_l"  type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_t"  type="text_sv"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_b"  type="boolean" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_f"  type="float"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_d"  type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_dt" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_p" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="false"/>


    <field name="placement" type="text_sv" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

    <field name="sls_archive_exact" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />

    <field name="type_exact" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

    <field name="sls_archive" type="text_sv" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />

    <field name="text" type="edge_ngram" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

    <field name="type" type="text_sv" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

    <field name="placement_exact" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

    <field name="place_exact" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />

    <field name="person" type="text_sv" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />

    <field name="person_exact" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />

    <field name="subject_exact" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />

    <field name="place" type="text_sv" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />

    <field name="subject" type="text_sv" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />

    <field name="dc_type_exact" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

    <field name="dc_type2_exact" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

    <field name="dc_type2" type="text_sv" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

    <field name="dc_type" type="text_sv" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

    <field name="person_auto" type="edge_ngram" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

  </fields>

  <!-- field to use to determine and enforce document uniqueness. -->
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

  <!-- field for the QueryParser to use when an explicit fieldname is absent -->
  <defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>

  <!-- SolrQueryParser configuration: defaultOperator="AND|OR" -->
  <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>
</schema>
```

Comment: Will your index be Swedish only?

Comment: Yes, it will. So it should be quite simple I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the below field type

```xml
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" preserveOriginal="1" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

And I searched the word mentioned by you "spelmansrörelse" ,  192b_2 or 367_3 and it works fine.

For more analysis check on solr analysis tool which you can access locally if you have solr running on your machine

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. What should I look for in the analysis tool?

Comment: If you are running solr on your machine then access it like http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/analysis.jsp                                               and if you have core created then  http://localhost:8983/solr/core_name/admin/analysis.jsp

Answer (score 0):

As you are going to fine tune your index for Swedish content I would strongly suggest to not use any out-of-the box stemming filters without knowing what they do. These are mostly geared for English content.

Have a look at [the Hunspellfilter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-HunspellStemFilter). As written in the SO [How to correctly configure solr stemming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516556/how-to-correctly-configure-solr-stemming) you can use the Swedish dictionary of OpenOffice to feed the Hunspellfilter with a dictionary and grammar file. This should produce better results for you.

And by any means, just use *one* stemming filter do not chain them.